# changing sdk version gives me confusing error messages

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-sdk-tools

I am migrating my App from Eclipse to AndroidStudio. My App was compiled with SDK 19. 
- I have my build.gradle with following settings:

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "company.app"
    minSdkVersion 12
    targetSdkVersion 19
    maxSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

Everything builds and I can start my app. -> ok

Now I want to change the compile SDK 19 as follow, but I can't build the project anymore :

```
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"
```

I get confusing messages, that doesn't say anything to me:

Messages :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDemo_testResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
```

Gradle Console:

```
invalid resource directory name: C:\Users\andreas\AndroidStudioProjects\Chronica\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\demo_test/drawable-anydpi-v21
invalid resource directory name: C:\Users\andreas\AndroidStudioProjects\Chronica\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\demo_test/values-b+sr+Latn


 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDemo_testResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 8.787 secs
```

I have installed SDK 19 and buildTools 19.

Can someone help me please ?